# How to change the color of searchbar search icon in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm developing an app that features a search bar, and it's functioning well in standard scenarios. However, I've encountered an issue when users activate the dark mode on their phones.

In the app's dark mode, the search bar icons turn white, which makes them difficult to distinguish. Although I've successfully managed to change the color of the cancel icon and text by using certain properties, I'm facing a challenge with altering the color of the search icon itself.

**Image when Dark mode is not activated:**
[image: Image when Dark mode is not activated]

**Image when Dark mode is activated:**
[image: Image when Dark mode is activated]

***Note: I am trying to get same result for dark mode activated or not.***

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use handlers this is a way to do that. This is just a simple OnPropertyChange and change the color of the icon for current platform to the same as the Text Color property. It is triggered by changes to the Text color so it follows Theme changes, both System and User. Read about how to implement Handlers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/) I have used filename-based multi-targeting for this.
The shared code will be in a file called `SearchBarExHandler.cs`:

```cs
public partial class SearchBarExHandler : SearchBarHandler
{
    public static readonly IPropertyMapper<ISearchBar, SearchBarHandler> CustomMapper =
        new PropertyMapper<ISearchBar, SearchBarHandler>(Mapper)
        {
            ["IconColor"] = MapIconColor,
        };

    public SearchBarExHandler() : base(CustomMapper, CommandMapper)
    {
    }

    public override void UpdateValue(string propertyName)
    {
        base.UpdateValue(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == SearchBar.TextColorProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            SetIconColor(GetTextColor());
        }
    }
}
```

Then we need files for the different platforms, `SearchBarExHandler.Android.cs`, `SearchBarExHandler.iOS.cs`, `SearchBarExHandler.Windows.cs`

**IOS**

```cs
public partial class SearchBarExHandler : SearchBarHandler
{
    public void SetIconColor(UIColor value)
    {
#if IOS13_0_OR_GREATER
        var textField = PlatformView.SearchTextField;
        var leftView = textField.LeftView ?? throw new Exception();
        leftView.TintColor = value;
#endif
    }

    private UIColor GetTextColor() => VirtualView.TextColor.ToPlatform();

    public static void MapIconColor(ISearchBarHandler handler, ISearchBar searchBar)
    {
        if (handler is SearchBarExHandler customHandler)
            customHandler.SetIconColor(customHandler.GetTextColor());
    }
}
```

**Android**

```cs
using AColor = Android.Graphics.Color;

public partial class SearchBarExHandler : SearchBarHandler
{
    public void SetIconColor(AColor value)
    {
        var searchIcon = (ImageView)PlatformView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.search_mag_icon);
        searchIcon.SetColorFilter(value, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
    }

    public AColor GetTextColor() => VirtualView.TextColor.ToAndroid();

    public static void MapIconColor(ISearchBarHandler handler, ISearchBar searchBar)
    {
        if (handler is SearchBarExHandler customHandler)
            customHandler.SetIconColor(customHandler.GetTextColor());
    }
}
```

**Windows**

```cs
using WColor = Windows.UI.Color;

namespace MauiTest.Handlers;

public partial class SearchBarExHandler : SearchBarHandler
{
    public void SetIconColor(WColor value)
    {
        PlatformView.QueryIcon.Foreground = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(value);
    }

    private WColor GetTextColor() => VirtualView.TextColor.ToWindowsColor();

    public static void MapIconColor(ISearchBarHandler handler, ISearchBar searchBar)
    {
        if (handler is SearchBarExHandler customHandler)
            customHandler.SetIconColor(customHandler.GetTextColor());
    }
}
```

Then you register the SearchBar in your app

```cs
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
    .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
    {
        handlers.AddHandler<SearchBar, SearchBarExHandler>();
    });
```

If you are going with multiple files like this don't forget to configure your project for this. Or you go for putting your complete files under Platform.

A fully working version of this can be found in my repo [here](https://github.com/PeterWessberg/MAUISamples)

Comment: This is an excellent answer and I've got it working on the Android side with one small snag. The condition `if (propertyName == SearchBar.TextColorProperty.PropertyName)` never evaluates to true, even though I'm setting `TextColor` property explicitly in xaml (and making sure it's a property *change*). Moving the expression `SetIconColor(GetTextColor())` out from this block demonstrates that things are working otherwise. Any idea what small thing I'm missing?

Comment: It works perfectly so there most be something with your configruation. I have put this in my [repo](https://github.com/PeterWessberg/MAUISamples) for you to examine. If you find a problem please let us discuss it.

Comment: The repo helps! I had left out `public SearchBarExHandler() : base(CustomMapper, CommandMapper) { }`. "One little mistake", right? Also, I noticed that having the one instance of MapIconColor in the shared code (as in your repo) is a little nicer than the three instances shown in the platform code (as shown above) but that's a style point only. The condition `(propertyName == SearchBar.TextColorProperty.PropertyName)` gets fired in response to [Toggle Text Color] in your demo. For a static one-time set, I left out `UpdateValue` entirely. It works now and I learned a ton. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, and next time you will help me. That is how this works. It is always good to remember that most answers on here never have clean cut ready to use code. It is often the bare minimum of code and often done so that it is clear and understandable. It is up to you to make it work in your user cases and your environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue about this problem, you can follow it up here: [Unable to change color of SearchBar magnifying glass icon](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6094).

This was inherited from `Xamarin.Forms`. And there is [an open PR](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/14766) here that makes the icon the same color as the text color.

Thans for your support and feedback for maui.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe create a custom control, that way i think is easier to manipulate those properties as you like. I've made one a while ago, and it looks pretty good IMP, i'll leave it here. Hope it might help you

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:CurrencyExchange.ViewModels"
             x:Class="CurrencyExchange.CustomControls.FilterControl"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:CurrencyExchange.Converters"
             xmlns:cstmctrls="clr-namespace:CurrencyExchange.CustomControls"
             x:Name="this">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <converters:EnableSearchButtonConverter x:Key="EnableSearchButton"/>
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <Frame Padding="5"
           Margin="10"
           WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="70"
           CornerRadius="30">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">

            <Entry x:Name="filterLabel"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   Placeholder="Insert the Location"
                   FontSize="18"
                   WidthRequest="200"
                   BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
                   Text="{Binding Filter}"/>

            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="{StaticResource SearchIcon}" FontFamily="FAS" FontSize="20" <!-- You could bind the text color, depending if the app is in dark mode or light mode -->
                    CornerRadius="50"
                    WidthRequest="50"
                    Margin="6"
                    BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference filterLabel}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource EnableSearchButton}}"
                    Command="{Binding Command}"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class FilterControl : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty FilterProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Filter), typeof(string), typeof(FilterControl), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnProperyChanged);
    public string Filter
    {
        get => GetValue(FilterProperty) as string;
        set => SetValue(FilterProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(FilterControl));
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get => GetValue(CommandProperty) as ICommand;
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }
    static void OnProperyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (newValue != oldValue)
        {
            var filterControl = bindable as FilterControl;
            filterControl?.SetControlValues((string)newValue);
        }
    }
    public void SetControlValues(string filter)
    {
        filterLabel.Text = filter;
    }
    public FilterControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
        if (Platform.CurrentActivity.CurrentFocus != null)
            Platform.CurrentActivity.HideKeyboard(Platform.CurrentActivity.CurrentFocus);
#endif
    }
}
```

You can then make your own tweaks as you like. (NOTE: in this case, you have to import FontAwesome Fonts)

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in the past and I have one solution and it's working for me in **dark** and **light** mode.

[SearchLight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMPEA.jpg)

Below is the .xaml code.

```
<Grid>
    <Frame
        Style="{DynamicResource SearchBarFrame}">
        <SearchBar 
            Placeholder="Search">
        </SearchBar>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

Set the `Frame` and `SearchBar` below style in `Styles.xaml`.

```
<Style x:Key="SearchBarFrame" TargetType="Frame">
    <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,1,1,-3"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="SearchBar">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
    <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray500}" />
    <Setter Property="CancelButtonColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray500}" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="44"/>
    <Setter Property="MinimumWidthRequest" Value="44"/>
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you need to hide the underline of SearchBar, you can achieve this with the above style.